# ng-include added addition div element

Tags: angularjs

**Navigation.html contents**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <div ng-include="AnnonymousTopHeaderUrl"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**AnnonymousNavigation.html contents**

```
<li>
    <a target="_self" href="#Register">Register</a>
</li>
```

**Base Controller is here**

```
myApp.controller("BaseController", ["$scope", function($scope) {                 
    $scope.AnnonymousTopHeaderUrl = "App/Include/AnnonymousNavigation.html";        
}]);
```

**When I run the code, it shows below Html**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- ngInclude: AnnonymousTopHeaderUrl -->
    <div ng-include="AnnonymousTopHeaderUrl" class="ng-scope">
        <li class="ng-scope">
            <a target="_self" href="#Register">Register</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

**I was expecting below Html**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a target="_self" href="#Register">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to get the expected Html?

Comment: pretty simple...`<div>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just place `ng-include` directive over `ul` element, so that it will not create unnecessary `div` element inside `ul`.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-include="AnnonymousTopHeaderUrl">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can u suggest something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378978/check-max-attempts-laravel-5